# Getting error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'myclass'

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a javascript kind of JSON

```
"{\n  \"resultSet1\": [\n    {\n      \"AgentID\": 13173,\n      \"FirstName\": \"Drilon\",\n      \"SG_ID\": 14336,\n      \"LoginName\": \"UI813926\",\n      \"SG_Description\": \"LKC Bauhotline\",\n      \"SG_Name\": \"Y_BAU__FO\",\n      \"EnterpriseName\": \"LKC_Abdullahu_Drilon\",\n      \"LastName\": \"Abdullahu\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"AgentID\": 14432,\n      \"FirstName\": \"Pinar\",\n      \"SG_ID\": 14336,\n      \"LoginName\": \"UI938008\",\n      \"SG_Description\": \"LKC Bauhotline\",\n      \"SG_Name\": \"Y_BAU__FO\",\n      \"EnterpriseName\": \"LKC_Ali_Pinar\",\n      \"LastName\": \"Ali\"\n    },  ]\n}"
```

Agents and Agent classes are

```
public class Agent
{
    public int AgentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int SG_ID { get; set; }
    public string LoginName { get; set; }
    public string SG_Description { get; set; }
    public string SG_Name { get; set; }
    public string EnterpriseName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Agents : IEnumerable<Agent>
{
    public List<Agent> resultSet1 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<Agent> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<Agent>)resultSet1).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)resultSet1).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

with Newtonsoft.json like this:

```
Agents result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Agents>(responseString);
```

And getting the following error:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name": "value"}) into type 'myclass' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

It is deserializing fine with the nancy.json library.

```
Agents AgentsData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Agents>(responseString);
```

Comment: can you check if responseString is wraped insede [ ] ?

Comment: Please provide the faulty JSON (`responseString`) and  code for `Agents`. I assume that `Agents` implement `IEnumerable` or inherit from some collection. AFAIK this is not supported by `JsonConvert`, possibly you will need either to workaround via DTO or custom converter.

Comment: JSON is coming from another API call and it is fine as it is deserializing accurately with the Nancy.json package.

Comment: _"and it is fine as it is deserializing accurately with the Nancy.json"_ - does not prove anything TBH =) But again highly likely that you need to remove the inheritance/collection interface from the class. Or provide the [mre] (which again includes JSON and type hierarchy).

Comment: Right Agents class is implementing `IEnumerable ` you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Agents` implements `IEnumerable<>`, mark it  with [`JsonObjectAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOverrideIEnumerable.htm) to enforce deserialization as/from object:

```cs
[JsonObject]
public class Agents : IEnumerable<Agent>
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check following points:

1. Make sure that Agents class has same keys as defined in json. It should be similar to below class

   ```
    public class Agents
    {
        public int AgentID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public int SG_ID { get; set; }
        public string LoginName { get; set; }
        public string SG_Description { get; set; }
        public string SG_Name { get; set; }
        public string EnterpriseName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
   ```
2. Also your json has data for multiple agent id, try below line to convert:

   ```
    List<Agents> AgentsData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Agents>>(responseString);
   ```